Apache Beam, Flink Runner, Clickhouse, Kafka, Java - pipeline isn't running
I'm trying to create a pipeline with Apache Beam and FlinkRunner to read messages from Kafka topic and to save them to ClickHouse DB.
When I run program via maven:
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.monitoring.KafkaToClickHouse \
    -Dexec.args="--runner=FlinkRunner \
      --flinkMaster=localhost:8081 \
      --filesToStage=target/monitoring-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
      --streaming"

it runs without errors, but do nothing, the process is working without any actions.
Log contains only:
Start program
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment (file:/C:/Users/Admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/flink/flink-core/1.5.6/flink-core-1.5.6.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.core.memory.HybridMemorySegment
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
▒▒▒ 31, 2024 10:50:08 AM org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent <clinit>
INFO: Your platform does not provide complete low-level API for accessing direct buffers reliably. Unless explicitly requested, heap buffer will always be preferred to avoid potential system unstability.

If I try to change some details in code, for example, change one of fields of ClickHouse table or to change kafka BootstrapServers url to unexisting one, it gives me an error according:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.3.0:java (default-cli) on project monitoring: 
An exception occurred while executing the Java class. Pipeline execution failed: Job execution failed. java.sql.SQLException: Code: 47. DB::Exception: 
Missing columns: 'gos_service1cxc' while processing query: 'SELECT gos_service1cxc, url, time_start, time_duration FROM monitoring_events WHERE 0', required columns: 'gos_service1cxc' 'time_start' 'url' 'time_duration', 
maybe you meant: ['gos_service','time_start','url','time_duration']. (UNKNOWN_IDENTIFIER) (version 21.11.5.33 (official build))
[ERROR] , server ClickHouseNode [uri=http://localhost:8123/default]@-1841500043


In case all data is correct, it seems to do nothing.
I tried to run it via DirectRunner as well - the same situation.
Main class:
package com.example.monitoring;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.apache.beam.runners.flink.FlinkRunner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.SerializableCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.kafka.KafkaIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Default;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.Description;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions.DirectRunner;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ValueProvider;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Values;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.TypeDescriptor;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

public class KafkaToClickHouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start program");

        PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create();

        //        tried this way - is not working as well
        // MyOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(MyOptions.class);

        options.setRunner(FlinkRunner.class);
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        pipeline
            .apply("ReadFromKafka", KafkaIO.<String, String>read()
                .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9094")
                .withTopic("monitoring-ping")
                .withKeyDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withValueDeserializer(StringDeserializer.class)
                .withReadCommitted()
                .withoutMetadata())
            .apply("ExtractValues", Values.<String>create())
            .apply("ParseJson", MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(MonitoringEvent.class))
                .via((String json) -> {
                    System.out.println("Received from kafka: " + json);
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    JsonNode jsonNode = null;
                    try {
                        jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return new MonitoringEvent(
                        jsonNode.get("gosService").asText(),
                        jsonNode.get("url").asText(),
                        jsonNode.get("timeStart").asText(),
                        jsonNode.get("timeDuration").asLong()
                    );
                }))
            .setCoder(SerializableCoder.of(MonitoringEvent.class))
            .apply("WriteToClickHouse", JdbcIO.<MonitoringEvent>write()
                .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                    "com.clickhouse.jdbc.ClickHouseDriver",
                    "jdbc:clickhouse://localhost:8123/default"))
                .withStatement("INSERT INTO monitoring_events (gos_service1cxc, url, time_start, time_duration) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")
                .withPreparedStatementSetter((JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<MonitoringEvent>) (element, query) -> {
                    System.out.println("Writing to db: " + element.toString());
                    query.setString(1, element.gosService);
                    query.setString(2, element.url);
                    query.setString(3, element.timeStart);
                    query.setLong(4, element.timeDuration);
                }));

        pipeline.run();

        System.out.println("End program");

    }

    public static class MonitoringEvent implements Serializable {
        public String gosService;
        public String url;
        public String timeStart;
        public long timeDuration;

        public MonitoringEvent(String gosService, String url, String timeStart, long timeDuration) {
            this.gosService = gosService;
            this.url = url;
            this.timeStart = timeStart;
            this.timeDuration = timeDuration;
        }
    }
}

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.monitoring</groupId>
  <artifactId>monitoring</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>8</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Apache Beam dependencies -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-flink_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-kafka</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
      <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ClickHouse dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.clickhouse</groupId>
      <artifactId>clickhouse-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.0-patch5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Kafka dependency -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
      <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON processing library -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.13.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.example.monitoring.KafkaToClickHouse</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>com.example.monitoring.KafkaToClickHouse</mainClass>
                </transformer>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>

What problem could be with my pipeline?
I tried to add some logging, but only first of it is displayed.
I also tried to run it via DirectRunner in debug mode with IntellijIdea doing step over - it always stands by on line PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create(); and then nothing is happend, the application is running and isn't stepping over to next lines.

Have you checked this? https://github.com/apache/beam-starter-java/blob/main/pom.xml#L94

Yeap, I've studied this as well. But there are no samples with Kafka or Clickhouse, only simple pipeline.

I mean you need to add the slf4j dependency to your pom.
